# React hooks: Why do several useState setters in an async function cause several rerenders?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

This following onClick callback function will cause 1 re-render:

```js
const handleClickSync = () => {
  // Order of setters doesn't matter - React lumps all state changes together
  // The result is one single re-rendering
  setValue("two");
  setIsCondition(true);
  setNumber(2);
};
```

React lumps all three state changes together and causes 1 rerender.

The following onClick callback function, however, will cause 3 re-renderings:

```js
const handleClickAsync = () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    // Inside of an async function (here: setTimeout) the order of setter functions matters.
    setValue("two");
    setIsCondition(true);
    setNumber(2);
  });
};
```

It's one re-render for every `useState` setter. Furthermore the order of the setters influences the values in each of these renderings.

**Question**: Why does the fact that I make the function async (here via `setTimeout`) cause the state changes to happen one after the other and thereby causing 3 re-renders. Why does React lump these state changes together if the function is synchronous to only cause one rerender?

You can play around with [this CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-usestate-setter-in-timeout-1ls9y?file=/src/App.js) to experience the behavior.

Comment: Because you are outside of react's own calls. In the first, react will call the click handler, and the setstate calls will be done, when it ends. In the second, it happens at an arbitrary time, and react therefore won't batch it. Read https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2020/05/blogged-answers-a-mostly-complete-guide-to-react-rendering-behavior/#render-batching-and-timing - or rather, the whole article. I consider it part of what anyone working with react should have read.

Comment: While it doesn't explain why, the [React documentation suggests](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#should-i-use-one-or-many-state-variables) _"[splitting] state into multiple state variables based on which values tend to change together."_ which means that whenever possible, using an object as the state if most values changes together would be fine.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In react 17, if code execution starts inside of react (eg, an `onClick` listener or a `useEffect`), then react can be sure that after you've done all your state-setting, execution will return to react and it can continue from there. So for these cases, it can let code execution continue, wait for the return, and then synchronously do a single render.

But if code execution starts randomly (eg, in a `setTimeout`, or by resolving a promise), then code isn't going to return to react when you're done. So from react's perspective, it was quietly sleeping and then you call `setState`, forcing react to be like "ahhh! they're setting state! I'd better render". There are async ways that react could wait to see if you're doing anything more (eg, a timeout 0 or a microtask), but there isn't a synchronous way for react to know when you're done.

You can tell react to batch multiple changes by using `unstable_batchedUpdates`:

```
import { unstable_batchedUpdates } from "react-dom";

const handleClickAsync = () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    unstable_batchedUpdates(() => {
      setValue("two");
      setIsCondition(true);
      setNumber(2);    
    });
  });
};
```

In version 18 this isn't necessary, since the changes they've made to rendering for concurrent rendering make batching work for all cases.

Comment: This also applies when you update states via manual event listeners e.g: `element.addEventListener()` for the same reason mentioned about updates triggered outside react.

Answer (score 19):

Right now react only batches sync `setState`s inside event handlers.
But in react 18 it will be available in `setTimeout`, `useEffect`s etc
Here is excellent explanation from Dan https://github.com/reactwg/react-18/discussions/21

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** **REACT 18 FEATURES AUTOMATIC BATCHING**

In React, Batching helps to reduce the number of re-renders that happen when state changes, when you call `setState()`. Previously, React batched state updates in event handlers, for example :

```
const handleClick = () => {
setCounter();
setActive();
setValue();
}

//re-rendered once at the end.
```

However, state updates that happened outside of event handlers were not batched. For example, if you had a promise or were making a network call, the state updates would not be batched. Like this:

```
fetch('/network').then( () => {
setCounter(); //re-rendered 1 times
setActive();  //re-rendered 2 times
setValue();   //re-rendered 3 times
});

//Total 3 re-renders
```

As you can tell, this is not performant. React 18 introduces automatic batching which allows all state updates – even within promises, setTimeouts, and event callbacks – to be batched. This significantly reduces the work that React has to do in the background. React will wait for a micro-task to finish before re-rendering.

Automatic batching is available out of the box in React, but if you want to opt-out you can use `flushSync`.

More Reading from FREECODECAMP RESOURCES: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/react-18-new-features/

Comment: by the way: are those setters going to be executed in the same order as they were called? What would happen if we called the ssame setter more than once and consecutive calls would depend on results of previous calls (ofc. using prevState => newState)?