# React: Combining vs separating state, and sequences of setters/dispatchers

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

### Setup

I'm creating a game in React, via a custom hook. It has many states to keep track of, and numerous constants which are calculated from those states.

For instance, there are states for the board, the history of all moves made, and who (if anyone) has forfeit, among others. And there are constants for what the game status is (ongoing, won, etc), who (if anyone) has won, who's turn is it, and more.

### "Related" States

In particular, the board and move history are very closely linked and should both update together. (In fact, the board could be calculated from the move history. But let's assume I don't want to do that and would prefer to keep the board as a state.)

Whenever someone makes a move, I need to update both of these. If they are separate states, then I need to use a sequence of two setters/dispatchers. **The potential problem here is that if React re-renders between these two, then the states will be out of sync** and some side effects (via `useEffect`s) will malfunction. I know that React bundles state updates, but this doesn't seem to be guaranteed when using asynchronous code (`setTimeout` to simulate a computer player thinking, for instance -- this has caused this exact problem to happen to me).

So, in a case like this, it seems most logical to bundle the two up into a single state object. (Correct me if I'm wrong.)

### "Independent" States

On the other hand, the board and whether anyone has forfeit are independent. You wouldn't generally expect these two states to update simultaneously. (And there are other examples of such pairs.)

In a case like this, it seems most logical to keep them as separate states. It would be possible to bundle them up together (along with the move history above), but that intuitively feels a bit wrong.

### The problem

So far everything seems to work fine following the strategies above of combining related states and keeping independent states separate.

Except, what about when I reset the game? While the board and who has forfeit are independent as mentioned above, I *do* in fact want to change them (and most of the other states) simultaneously when resetting the game. If many of these states are separate, then I have to (as far as I can tell) use a sequence of setters/dispatchers to update each in turn. (They can't happen via a side-effect because they'll be 'out of sync' before the side-effect happens, and they can't be stateless and calculated from the other states because of their nature.)

And we're back to **the problem of a possible re-render in the middle of this sequence**. (Again, this seems to be rare, but does seem to happen when using async code.)

Following my reasoning above, it seems that the solution is to combine all states that need resetting into a single state. The conclusion then is that for most hooks that I make, most/all of the states should be bundled up into a single state. But it seems odd to have to always do this -- conceptually separate concepts seem like they should stay in separate states.

(One could try to order the setter/dispatch calls in such a way that nothing bad would happen in the middle, but that may not always be possible, and even if it is, it seems like a bad way to get around the problem.)

### Questions

Have I made a mistake somewhere in my reasoning? Do I really need to combine all my states into one state just so that resetting the game works, or are there alternative ways to deal with this problem of having separate states 'out of sync'?

(In this particular case, a reset could possibly be achieved by unmounting and remounting the component which calls the hook, but in other cases that might not be possible if some state needs to be preserved during the reset -- or if the action isn't a reset.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A similar question [React hooks: Why do several useState setters in an async function cause several rerenders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69855485/react-hooks-why-do-several-usestate-setters-in-an-async-function-cause-several) has answers which ultimately address this question.

**No, it's not necessary to combine all states into a single state just to make sure resetting goes smoothly.** You can use `unstable_batchedUpdates` to prevent React from rerendering between setters (see question linked above for details and an example).

And in fact, in React 18, `unstable_batchedUpdates` won't even be necessary -- React will automatically handle batching for events coming from async calls (like `setTimeout`, and more) the same as how it currently handles them for React events. See [this GitHub discussion](https://github.com/reactwg/react-18/discussions/21) for full details and examples.