# Does order of state variable matters in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

When I execute the code below gives an error "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'login')", because it reaches the return statement at the end, which it should not as I already have checks for the boolean before return.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
const url = 'https://api.github.com/users/QuincyLarsn';
const MultipleReturns = () => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false);
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(url)
      .then(data => {
        if (data.status >= 200 && data.status <= 299)
          return data.json();
        else {
          console.log("here");
          setIsLoading(false);
          setIsError(true);
          console.log("here 2");
        }
      })
      .then(result => {
        setIsLoading(false);
        setUser(result);
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error))
  }, []);

  console.log(isError);
  if (isLoading)
    return <h2>Loading...</h2>
  if (isError) {
    return <h2>Error...</h2>
  }

  return <h2>{user.login}</h2>

};

export default MultipleReturns;
```

In the above code if setIsError(true) is placed before setIsLoading(false) in useEffect, then everything works fine but not vice versa, similarly if the url is correct then too things work fine if setUser(result) is placed before setIsLoading(false) and not vice versa.
I am not able to figure out why that is the case.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind, the "`setXYZ`" functions returned by `useState` do not update the state immediately, but "schedule" the update instead.

Comment: You are passing `null` as initial value of user, so, if you try to read property of null, it will result in error. Maybe you should consider using `user?.login`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React hooks: Why do several useState setters in an async function cause several rerenders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69855485/react-hooks-why-do-several-usestate-setters-in-an-async-function-cause-several)

Comment: TL;DR, it's not the order, it's the fact that there's multiple setters called in an async function that triggers multiple re-renders (with each state update).

Comment: Also, you need to return a value in the else clause. Otherwise for error cases, `user` value will be `undefined`.

Comment: why does having "{user?.login}" or having a default value in useState for user does not cause this issue?

Comment: @tedlennen the issue would still be present, but the actual error would be ignored by proper checks (`user?.`) The best solution would be to [create an object state](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#should-i-use-one-or-many-state-variables) that you can set all at once. `setState({ error: true, isLoading: false })`

Comment: ok got that point

Answer (score 1):

React is not batching state updates from `fetch()`. It is batched in case of event listeners. This is an async fetch call.

In this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-mahavira-vxycz?file=/src/App.js) console, you can see that there is a render in between your state updates - `setIsLoading(false)` and `setIsError(true)`.

So for one render cycle : `isLoading` is false and `isError` is also false. That will lead to the error condition.

You can use unstable_batchedUpdates to enforce batching.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { unstable_batchedUpdates } from "react-dom";
import "./styles.css";

const url = "https://api.github.com/users/QuincyLarsn";
const App = () => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false);
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(url)
      .then((data) => {
        if (data.status >= 200 && data.status <= 299) return data.json();
        else {
          console.log("here");
          unstable_batchedUpdates(() => {
            setIsLoading(false);
            setIsError(true);
          });
          console.log("here 2");
        }
      })
      .then((result) => {
        setIsLoading(false);
        setUser(result);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }, []);

  console.log("isError", isError);
  if (isLoading) return <h2>Loading...</h2>;
  if (isError) return <h2>Error...</h2>;

  return <h2>{user.login}</h2>;
};

export default App;
```

[Corrected Sandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-matan-9ddcw?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: This is already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69855485/1218980

Comment: I am new to this concept of batching, can you suggest me where can I learn more about it?

Answer (score 1):

In a such case, order does matter.

While React may batch updates in this case, it's not guaranteed and even if it does, it may call the render function with the in-between state.

So, when `isLoading` is set to `false`, but `user` is not yet set, you get an error.

You can fix this by setting the `user` first, and then making `isLoading` `false`.

But the real solution would be to eliminate the unnecessary state variables: `isLoading` is `true` while `isError` is `false` and `user` is `null`, and `false` otherwise.

So, you can do it like this:

should not as I already have checks for the boolean before return.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
const url = 'https://api.github.com/users/QuincyLarsn';
const MultipleReturns = () => {
  const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false);
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(url)
      .then(data => {
        if (data.status >= 200 && data.status <= 299)
          return data.json();
        else {
          console.log("here");
          setIsError(true);
          console.log("here 2");
        }
      })
      .then(result => {
        setUser(result);
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error))
  }, []);

  console.log(isError);
  if (isError) {
    return <h2>Error...</h2>
  }
  if (user !== null) {
    return <h2>{user.login}</h2>
  }
  return <h2>Loading...</h2>
};

export default MultipleReturns;
```

Answer (score 0):

After you set isLoading as false, the code moves to the last return statement as the error is still false at the moment. So first setting the error blocks the code at the second return statement.

Similarly if you set isLoading as false then set the user, the code will move to the last return statement before the user is set and it will show error. Setting the user and then making isLoading as false shows the user perfectly.