# Is React Hooks SetState async?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a question regarding hooks and set State. Let's take very basic example.
Suppose I have one input box and button, which is a very common use case. Whenever i type in input box, and click on button, button click handler should reflect the latest state.
On stackoverflow, I saw below code to do the activity:

```
const input = props => {  
  const [textInput, setTextInput] = React.useState('');

  const handleClick = () => {
    console.log(textInput);
    props.send(textInput);
  }

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setTextInput(event.target.value);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input onChange={handleChange} placeholder="Type a message..." />
      <div onClick={handleClick} className="icon">
        <i className="fa fa-play" />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Isnt above setTextInput(event.target.value);  input async as react does batching? So when user clicks on submit, how do i know that state is actually updated? . This is a very basic use case and i don't want to use useRef as this must be a common problem or am i missing something?

**Note:** In above solution, we want to read the state only after both the conditions are satisfied:

1. User has clicked button.
2. State has been updated by setState

Comment: It seems like the term `async` is causing you to believe that state updates are made after an interval or something of that nature, but you can *always* trust that state has been updated on the *next render*. Meaning, when `handleClick` is called, any queued state changes from `handleChange` are guaranteed to have been made already.

Comment: Unless you [call multiple state setter functions inside an async callback](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69855485/1218980), which wouldn't render with the absolute latest state immediately (each setter called will trigger a render), but it's more of an edge case.

Comment: @BrianThompson So When to trust this state, i.e. sometimes we say, that dont read state directly use useEffect, sometimes we say, trust the state like you said. So how to be 100% sure. If above code is run 100 times, will i be 100% sure, that state will be updated in all 100 times? if yes, then where is its batching.async and  why people avoid reading from states directly and prefer useEffect

Comment: Inside `handleChange`, the value of `textInput` won't change, but on the next render, it's going to be updated since the `useState` hook will return the up-to-date value.

Comment: @abhinavbansal Async is only half of the problem in function components. You also have the issue of closures, and the fact that `textInput` is a `const` which **cannot** ever change. Problems you're referring to are found when calling state updaters multiple times or trying to use the updated state before the next render. Neither of those happen here, so you have nothing to worry about. You may trust it to be up-to-date 100% of the time in the code provided.

Comment: hmm.. You said:
"trying to use the updated state before the next render."
what if handleClick is called first by react and render(because of handleChange) happened afterwards?

Comment: @abhinavbansal I'm not following that completely, but I still think I can address your doubts - It's not possible for both the `handleClick` and `handleChange` functions to be called without a render in between, regardless of which is called first (with how the code is currently written). They are event handlers, and maybe someone else can help me find supporting docs, but you cannot fire two event handlers at the same time, so there will always be a re-render before the second event is fired.

Comment: hmm if that is the case, that resolves my doubt. Thank you so much for taking out your time to resolve my doubt :D appreciate it

Comment: "Is React Hooks SetState async?" - No, it's a completely synchronous function, in other words, it's not declared `async` nor does it return a Promise. What ***is asynchronous*** is the processing of enqueued state updates though. As Brian says, you can count on the state being the updated value by the next render cycle when a user can click/submit the form.

Comment: @BrianThompson Can you please post your answer? i want to mark it as best answer.

Answer (score 0):

In my limited knowledge, `setState` is in fact asynchronous. It does not interrupt other processes to carry out setting the state. It is queued to be executed on the next batch.

The situation you are talking about here will never have the async nature of `setState` cause problems. The action of the user clicking will always happen after the newState is set.